# ffmpeg save jpeg image from HDMI Capture

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on a project where I need to capture one image from an HDMI Capture card and then process it. I am using the following code:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -ss 00:00:05 -vframes 1 -s 1920x1080 output.jpg")
```

No, I am getting the jpg files sometimes ok, but sometimes noise like following

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv8sf.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adbn6.jpg)

Can someone please help me with what should be the issue?

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1449252) help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.